# How to resolve eslint missing key prop for element in array when not iterating?

Tags: reactjs, key, eslint

For the following code, `eslint` throws an error for `react/jsx-key: Missing 'key' prop for element in array`.

I know I need to add keys to my array but I don't know where and how!

How do I resolve?

```js
export default function App() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setStep((step) => [1, 2, 0][step]);
  }

  const ComponentList = [
    <div>Step 1</div>,
    <div>Step 2</div>,
    <div>Step 3</div>
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment Step</button>
      {ComponentList[step]}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggested to use index as key, you should use an unique identifier but take this as an example.

```js
export default function App() {
      const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

      function handleClick() {
        setStep((step) => [1, 2, 0][step]);
      }

      const ListItem = (step) => (<div>`Step ${step}`</div>)

      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment Step</button>
          <ListItem item={step}>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

in this example ListItem doesn't even need to have a key since we are not iterating through an array. but if it was an array, it'd be:

```
list.map(step => <ListItem step={step} key={`list-item-${step.toString()}`}>)
```